# Modal is auto hiding?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, modal-dialog

In my view, I get the form as below, but as soon as I click on "click me", the popup appears and disappears automatically. Why is it disappearing automatically ?

I have the view :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2>Hello world</h2>',
    'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'click me'],
]);

echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

Modal::end();
```

and the form :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => ['entype' => 'multipart/form-data']
]); ?>

.....
.....
.....

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Could I see some working examples on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modal dialog is working for me from your example. I hope may me some java script is getting triggered while clicking 'click me' button. Try to remove your custom java script script files or custom codes from that page and try once please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably load Bootstrap JavaScript twice, you may load it once in a bundle, and DatePicker/ActiveForm/Modal may load it again within their own bundles. Please check the asset bundles that get loaded, Yii2 debugger provides a custom view named Asset Bundles that allows you to see what bundles and what files were loaded.

Comment: After removing `'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',` in `assets/AppsAssets.php`, it started working.

Comment: but i see in sites where datepicker & activeForms & Modal not used, I get `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. How do I handle it ?

Comment: You need to load `YiiAsset` in the main bundle of your app (by default, `AppAsset`), the `YiiAsset` depends on `JqueryAsset` and will load jQuery for you.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I see the layout (Charisma) is using its own jquery. Things work when I disable `YiiAsset`, but it disables `Datatables`. Is there a way I could handle it ?